# Resources error for object cotaining array as one field. Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am recieving an object from database that as array in it as one of the field. Here is sample of it

```
[
  {
    "isAlive": true,
    "idNumber": "34543"
    "newStruct": [
      {
        "login_name": "tjames",
        "message": "approved",
      },
      {
        "login_name": "tjames",
        "message": "approved",
      },
      {
         "login_name": "tjames",
        "message": "approved",
      }
    ],
    "ts": "/Date(-62135575200000-0600)/"
  }
]

App.factory("AppRepository", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {

        Overview: $resource('/api/Overview/Getinfo/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            update: { method: 'PUT' },
            query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
    });
}]);
```

Problem I am running into it is when I set

```
isArray:false it gives me error "Expected response to contain an object but got an array"
```

When i set

```
 isArray: True I get apposite 
"Expected response to contain an array but got an object"
```

Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: there is a missing "," after "idNumber": "34543"

Comment: final key val pair is not allowed to be followed by "," too. check your json string on jsonlint.com